# What for is a .cer file in iOS?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I wonder what for is .cer file in iOS when you want to publish an app in App Store.
I know I need .p12 file to publish an app. But I don't know why I need .cer file.

Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL has been around for long enough you'd think that there would be agreed upon container formats. And you're right, there are. Too many standards as it happens. So this is what I know, and I'm sure others will chime in

- `.pem` - Defined in RFCs [1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421)through [1424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1424), this is a container format that may include just the public certificate (such as with Apache installs, and CA certificate files /etc/ssl/certs), or may include an entire certificate chain including public key, private key, and root certificates. Confusingly, it may also encode a CSR  as the PKCS10 format can be translated into PEM. The name is from [Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail), a failed method for secure email but the container format it used lives on, and is a base64 translation of the x509 ASN.1 keys.
- `.cert` .`cer` .`crt` - A `.pem` (or rarely .der) formatted file with a different extension, one that is recognized by Windows Explorer as a certificate, which .pem is not.
- .`pkcs12 .pfx .p12` - Originally defined by RSA in the [Public-Key Cryptography Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) (abbreviated PKCS), the "12" variant was originally enhanced by Microsoft, and later submitted as [RFC 7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292). This is a passworded container format that contains both public and private certificate pairs. Unlike .pem files, this container is fully encrypted. Openssl can turn this into a .pem file with both public and private keys: `openssl pkcs12 -in file-to-convert.p12 -out converted-file.pem -nodes`

**Note**
There are a lot of articles about these, it is a very broad question.

Answer (score 2):

CER is a file extension for an SSL certificate file format used by Web servers to help verify the identity and security of the site in question. SSL certificates are provided by a third-party security certificate authority such as VeriSign, GlobalSign or Thawte.

From https://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/CER-Certificate-file-MIME-x-x509-ca-cert